# What would be a theologically sound and measured response to Joan Osbourne's "One of us"?

Tags: apologetics

That song was a big song in the 90s. What would be a orthodox response to the views in that song be? God was indeed one of us for a while. God does indeed have a name and yes he is called that "to his face" in the Bible. I do ask this question in good faith. I know expecting sound theology from random rock singers may very well be wishful thinking, but if more religiously educated people on this SE were confronted with a person who said things like that, what would your reply be?

Okay, I'm willing to go for a Dutch reformists point of view. You can add a sprinkling of Calvinism and a dash of Lutheran to the mix, but only if it helps this question stay open.

Comment: Dang, do I ever want to answer this, can you phrase this question so it doesn't specifically solicit opinion from the peanut gallery of "religiously educated C.SE inhabitants".   Are you really asking, "do Christians believe that Creator of the Universe would be a hipster (let alone Alanis Morrissette)  if He came in 1993?"

Comment: Specifically these types of things were things I would have said in certain times in my life. By replying to miss Osbourne you would also be replying to me.

Comment: I have made an edit in attempt to make a definite answer possible.

Comment: nice, it's a very slow work day - I'm trying to come up with a Sola Scriptura answer, hopefully it meets the criteria.  I asked a similar question on the Hindu stackexchange about Taylor Swift's new Karma song.  Apparently that's not what karma is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a verse vs verse breakdown of the song might be as follows:

> If God had a name what would it be?
>
> > 'I AM has sent me to you.'
> >
> > Exodus 3:14

> Would you call it to His face, if you were faced with Him?
>
> > But you may not look directly at my face, for no one may see me and live.
> >
> > Exodus 33:20

> What would you ask?
>
> > Jesus remember me, when you come into your kingdom
> >
> > Luke 23:42

> God is great
>
> > The temple I am going to build will be great, because our God is greater than all other gods
> >
> > 2 Chronicles 2:5

> God is good.
>
> > "Why do you call Me good?" Jesus replied. "No one is good except God alone."
> >
> > Mark 10:18

> What if God was one of us?
>
> > "And they shall call his name Emmanuel, which being interpreted is, God with us"
> >
> > Matthew 1:23

> Just a slob like one of us?
>
> > "He had nothing in his appearance that would make us desire him"
> >
> > Isaiah 53:2

> Just a stranger on the bus
>
> > Lord when did we see you?
> >
> > Matthew 25:44

> Tryin to make His way home.
>
> > I am ascending to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God.
> >
> > John 20:17

> If God has a face, what would it look like?
>
> > [Omitted]
> >
> > Exodus 20:4

> And would you want to see?
>
> > He wanted to see who Jesus was, but because he was short he could not see over the crowd. So he ran ahead and climbed a sycamore-fig tree to see him, since Jesus was coming that way.
> >
> > Luke 19:3-4

> If seeing meant that you would have to believe in things like Heaven and in Jesus and the saints and all the prophets
>
> > Have you believed because you have seen me? Blessed are those who have not seen and yet have believed
> >
> > John 20:29

> Back up to Heaven *all alone*
>
> > And suddenly there appeared with the angel a great multitude of the heavenly host, praising God
> >
> > Luke 2:13

> Nobody callin' on the phone, except for the Pope maybe in Rome
>
> > As soon as Peter was frightened, he started sinking and, therefore, cried to Jesus saying "Lord, save me".
> >
> > Matthew 14:30

Anyone who believes that God became man and sent God to dwell among us and sends Him still in the indwelling of the Holy Spirit and that God should be recognized in each and every neighbor who we can love and serve.

The fundamental idea that, if God was one of us, we should act like it.  Christians believe that God *is* one of us so we should treat our brothers and sisters accordingly.

Furthermore, as Christians, we should seek to contemplate His Holy Face, and we should pray to Him (as a means of 'calling' Him) not just leave it up to the Pope.

Comment: Is there a Biblical scene were Jesus ask disciples how they could expect anyone who comes after to believe when his own disciples question him? I seem to want to think there is.

Comment: @neil maybe luke 17:20-37?  Fresh in my head from Mass last weekend.